# Socket.io in flask: Data from external source

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have a web application and need to continuously display the actions going on in the backend on the browser. I have been trying to use socket.io in Flask. But I need to get the data to be displayed from other Python modules in my project. So, I tried to make a socket connection between Flask and the external module from which I will be getting data to be displayed on the browser(without any delay).

```
@socketio.on('my event')
def server(message):
    s = socket.socket()       
    print "Socket successfully created"
    port = 12345               
    s.bind(('', port))        
    print "socket binded to %s" %(port)
    s.listen(5)     
    print "socket is listening"           
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()     
        print 'Got connection from', addr
        print c.recv(1024)
        emit('my response', {'data': c.recv(1024)})
        c.close()
```

`print c.recv(1024)` is printing data on the console. But the same data is not getting reflected on the browser. It's throwing this error -

> error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

This means it's failing at `emit` after `print c.recv(1024)`. What could be going wrong?
My first doubt is if this kind of connection is allowed. I mean, can we have a socket connection created inside socket.io in Flask? 
Else, what is the best solution to display the backend actions on the browser continuously using Flask? I also have the web application with Django. Any solution for my use case with either Flask or Django will be appreciated (preferably Django).

Answer (score 4):

Using the answer given by Miguel, I could find an appropriate solution. In the external script, we need to create a `SocketIO` object as follows:

```
socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')
```

Then I can use `emit` to send the data to be displayed on the front end.

```
def fn():
    socketio.emit('my response', {'data': 'ur data goes here'})

fn()
```

And on the frontend,

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
socket.on('connect', function() {
socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
    $('#log').append('<p>Received: ' + msg.data + '</p>');
    document.getElementById('<div_id>').innerHTML += msg.data + "<br>";
    });
});
```

Finally, on the Flask server side, we need to create the `SocketIO` object as follows:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')
```

Then run Flask with `socketio.run(app,host='<ip>',port=<port>)`

Comment: If using Redis you will be most likely required to add two lines: ```import eventlet``` and

```eventlet.monkey_patch()``` at the top of the file with Flask app.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each time a client sends the event named `my event` to your server, you will try to start a new socket server on port 12345. Obviously this is only going to work the first time.

Have you seen the [Emitting from an External Process](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#emitting-from-an-external-process) section in the documentation?

The idea is that you can emit events to clients from any auxiliary process, which is exactly what you need. The solution involves installing a message queue (Redis, RabbitMQ), to which the Flask-SocketIO server and the external processes that need to have emit powers connect to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Miguel.